# Adding folder containing jars in java multimodule project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am a newbie in Gradle and I have the following java project structure:

```
rootProject
|--- projectA
|-------src/main/java
|-------build.gradle
|--- Lib
|-------lib/*.jar
|--- build.gradle
|--- settings.gradle
```

I am trying to build projectA. Project A dependencies are in Lib/lib folder as jars. I know that it is better to download these jars from maven central but now I have to maintain this structure.
So I am not aware how to add all the jars that are in Lib folder in projectA/build.gradle .
Can anyone help?

My build.gradle file in projectA is the following

```
apply plugin : "java"
task listJars<< {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
}
dependencies{
    compile fileTree(dir:'Lib/lib',include:'*.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add them as dependencies in a file object as such

```
dependencies {
   runtime files('libs/a.jar', 'libs/b.jar')
   runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') 
}
```

This was pulled form documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies)

Comment: But in my case libs is not the same folder. It is ../Libs/libs which seems not to work

Comment: so your case would be `runtime fileTree(dir: 'Libs/libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: Can you include your gradle file? you may also need to change it from runtime to compiile

Comment: i included the build.gradle file

Comment: Is your subdirectory lib or libs? It's listed as lib in your tree but libs in your gradle file

Comment: it is lib..i changed it but still this is not the issue